# Eclipse - Fold jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, folding

My javascript file is getting longer and longer, and I need to control my code.

I have jQuery functions written like this:

```
jQuery.fn.myFunction = function(){

}
```

Is there a way to fold/collapse these code blocks in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work-around in Eclipse that has worked for me is to give the function a name, even
if you don't use it. So,

jQuery.fn.myFunction = function whatever(){
 ...
}

Answer (score 0):

When you install the *JavaScript Development Tools* from the *Eclipse Web Tools Platform* you get code folding for Javascript (plus syntax highlighting). You can install it by selecting *Install New Software...* in the *Help* menu. Then search for *Javascript* and you'll find it.

Comment: This did not help with the jQuery functions. If i write a normal JS function, code folding works fine.